# How do I attach a sourcemap to a node.js (V8) CPU profile (.cpuprofile) in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, v8, profiler

I've used the Node.js [Inspector](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/inspector.html#cpu-profiler) module to produce a CPU profile (.cpuprofile file) from a production server.  I'm able to load it into chrome dev tools (Performance tab) without issue.

The flame graph and supporting function calls are great, but without being able to link up my source map(s) I'm unable to decipher the calls due to my preprocessor.

You can attach JS source maps when using chrome tools to debug JS on the page (sources tab).  How can I attach my source maps to a profile I uploaded to chrome dev tools (Performance tab)?

**Note**: I am using one of the [officially supported](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/#use_a_supported_preprocessor) preprocessors.

Comment: It is not possible to attach sourcemap in the Performance panel currently. I've created a feature request on behalf: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1344365. Feel free to put in more details and comment.